# Prime implicant and essential prime implicant problem

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Hello I had a question in my exam that asks how many prime implicants and essential prime implicant with this k-map below.
[image]I tried it and it's came with me 6 essential prime and also 6 prime. I got wrong answer with this question. Please correct my answer[image]

Comment: Do you have any feedback on the "correct" answer or the options available for it?

Comment: @DanSheppard I don't remember well but it's either (4 prime and 2 essential) or (2 prime 4 essential)

Comment: Ok, so the total's still six, and they're considering the categories exclusive (which is weird). I don't think there's any practical impact on your understanding here. I would say all six of your PIs are essential as they all uniquely encompass at least one minterm. I think your understanding matches mine, so either someone needs to correct us both or I need to wait what your professor says!

Comment: @DanSheppard I asked my professor and she said that just green, purple,pink and red is essential prime and the yellow and blue not essential because they can group with two minters  this rule is what our book depends on but there are other books don't say that.